# How to define a constant using another one in a Matlab class

Tags: matlab, matlab-class

I can't figure out how to do such a simple thing like defining constants using other ones.

For instance, a dummy example :

```
classdef DummyClass < handle
    properties (Constant)
        NB_SECONDS_IN_MINUTE = 60;
        NB_MINUTES_IN_HOUR   = 60;

        NB_SECONDS_IN_HOUR   = NB_SECONDS_IN_MINUTE * NB_MINUTES_IN_HOUR;
    end
end
```

This does not work :(

I then tried with this line :

```
NB_SECONDS_IN_HOUR   = DummyClass.NB_SECONDS_IN_MINUTE * DummyClass.NB_MINUTES_IN_HOUR;
```

but that doesn't work either...

Someone got a clue here ? :/

(I'm using MATLAB R2009a btw)

Comment: it said "undefined variable or class DummyClass".
btw, Edric gave me the solution : i just forgot that my class was in a subfolder, and in Matlab, one needs to use the fully qualified name of a class (including sub-directories)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You definitely need to refer to the constants with the full class name, as in your second case. Is `DummyClass` within a package (`+packagename`) directory? If so, you need to use the fully qualified name, i.e.

```
NB_SECONDS_IN_HOUR = packagename.DummyClass.NB_SECONDS_IN_MINUTE * packagename.DummyClass.NB_SECONDS_IN_HOUR;
```

EDIT: just tested this in R2009a:

```
>> ver matlab
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[...]
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MATLAB                                                Version 7.8        (R2009a)
>> type DummyClass

classdef DummyClass < handle
    properties (Constant)
        NB_SECONDS_IN_MINUTE = 60;
        NB_MINUTES_IN_HOUR   = 60;

        NB_SECONDS_IN_HOUR   = DummyClass.NB_SECONDS_IN_MINUTE * DummyClass.NB_MINUTES_IN_HOUR;
    end
end

>> DummyClass.NB_SECONDS_IN_HOUR
ans =
        3600
```

Comment: So it depends on the path where we code the class??? (and so we can't reuse this class directly in anoter project without the same directories structure?)

Comment: It only matters if you place DummyClass.m in a MATLAB *package* directory, i.e. one beginning with "+". When you do that, you alter the fully-qualified name of the class.